# Worker Service dynamically changing execution interval

Tags: c#

I have a worker service with the base class for all workers, which accepts the `IOptionsMonitor` constructor parameter. This monitor contains options object instance with the execution interval value. The question is how to dynamically change the interval, even when the `await Task.Delay(Interval);` was called? I mean if the `Interval` value is set to one day, and after the `Task.Delay` method being called it changes, for example, to one hour - I still need to wait one day and only on the next call the delay would be updated. How I can cancel the current delay and start a new one if the property `Interval` value was updated?
Thanks.

Please see the code attached below:

```
public abstract class WorkerBase<TWorker, TWorkerOptions> : BackgroundService
    where TWorker : WorkerBase<TWorker, TWorkerOptions>
    where TWorkerOptions : IHaveIntervalProperty
{
    protected WorkerBase(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<TWorker> logger, IOptionsMonitor<TWorkerOptions> options)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _workerName = typeof(TWorker).Name;
        Interval = options.CurrentValue.Interval;
        options.OnChange(UpdateOptions);
    }

    public TimeSpan Interval { get; private set; }

    public virtual void UpdateOptions(TWorkerOptions options)
        => Interval = options.Interval;

    public abstract Task DoWork(IServiceProvider provider);

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(Logs.InformationWorkerRunning, _workerName, DateTime.UtcNow);

            try
            {
                using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
                await DoWork(scope.ServiceProvider);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogCritical(e, e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                await Task.Delay(Interval, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `await Task.Delay`. Use a timer instead. If you change the timer internal, the new value will apply immediatelly. Besides, `Task.Delay` uses a timer itself. If you don't dispose the task it returns, that timer leaks. This means that the current code leaks timers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, wow, I completely forgot about timers. Thank you for your help. You can post an answer and I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, but the way, could you please attach a small code example? I am currently a bit confused about what class to use, `Timer` or `DispatcherTimer` or something else. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so based on @Panagiotis Kanavos comment I came up with the following code:

```
public abstract class RepeatableWorker<TWorker, TOptions> : IHostedService, IDisposable
    where TWorker : RepeatableWorker<TWorker, TOptions>
    where TOptions : IHaveIntervalProperty
{
    #region Fields
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private protected readonly ILogger<TWorker> _logger;
    private readonly string _workerName;
    private Timer? _executionTimer;
    private TimeSpan _interval;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    protected RepeatableWorker(IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
                               ILogger<TWorker> logger,
                               IOptionsMonitor<TOptions> options)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger;
        _workerName = typeof(TWorker).Name;
        _interval = options.CurrentValue.Interval;
        options.OnChange(UpdateOptions);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public TimeSpan Interval
    {
        get => _interval;
        private set
        {
            if (value != _interval)
            {
                _executionTimer?.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, value);
                _interval = value;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public methods
    public virtual void UpdateOptions(TOptions options)
        => Interval = options.Interval;

    public abstract void DoWork(IServiceProvider serviceProvider);

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(Logs.InformationWorkerStarting, _workerName, DateTime.UtcNow);
        _executionTimer = new(DoWorkInternal, null, TimeSpan.Zero, Interval);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(Logs.InformationWorkerStopping, _workerName, DateTime.UtcNow);
        _executionTimer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

        _executionTimer?.Dispose();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private methods
    private void DoWorkInternal(object? state)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker {0} running at {1}.", _workerName, DateTime.UtcNow);
            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            DoWork(scope.ServiceProvider);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogCritical(e, e.Message);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And the `IHaveIntervalProperty` interface:

```
public interface IHaveIntervalProperty
{
    TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }
}
```

Just in case someone will need such a solution.