# OnPause/OnContinue on Worker Service

Tags: c#, .net, service

I'm migrating a Windows Service from .Net Framework to .Net Core.
So i'm planning to create Worker Service project and use the [BackroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) class.

However, `BackgroundService` class does not have `OnPause` and `OnContinue` methods.

Is there a way/alternative where i can define `OnPause/OnContinue` for a Windows Service in .Net Core 3.1?

Comment: I think that you can't create a 1:1 map between the "old" windows service application and the new .NET core worker service model. The main difference, based on my understanding, is that a Windows Service is highly integrated with the Windows OS, it's the operating system which is meant to schedule the execution of the service. In the execution model of a windows service the OnPase and OnContinue make sense, because you can pause and continue a window service.

Comment: A .NET core worker service based on a .NET core host is a different beast. It is not meant to be tightly coupled with the Windows OS and it is not meant to be scheduled and executed by the Windows services infrastructure. Typically a .NET core worker service is deployed as a docker containers (it's not mandatory, but it's a quite common choice) and a container orchestrator is used to schedule its execution. That's why you can't find a direct equivalent of OnPause and OnContinue for a .NET core worker service.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that if you want to migrate your Windows Service application to a .NET core worker service you probably need to rethink and / or redesign it's execution model. It seems that you can actually leverage the Windows services infrastructure to schedule and execute a .NET core worker service. Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service#prerequisites

Comment: The stuff that in my previous comments I have called the Windows Service Infrastructure is actually called Service Control Manager in windows. Sorry, I didn't remember the correct name, hope you get the point anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68278587/12305721).
Based on the accepted answer (which is also mine), you could also define your methods and invoke them when the execution interval is set to 0 (`OnPause`) or any other value (`OnContinue`).